# Restating the condition for differentiability - is it equivalent?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Wikipedia states the following condition for a function to be differentiable at $x=a$:

> The derivative $f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists

For basic piecewise-defined functions with polynomial rules, I've been sketching the derivative and noticed the following: at the "swap-over" values of $x=a$ where the piecewise function changes rules, if $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)$ does not exist, then the function is not differentiable at $x=a$.

I'm just wondering if the statement "A function is differentiable at $x=a$ if $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists" is an equivalent statement? This is of course assuming the function is continuous at $x=a$.

Edit: updated to reflect another related question. Is the following opposing statement true?: If $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)$ does not exist, then the function is not differentiable at $x=a$

Comment: A standard counter-example: $f(x)=x^{2}\sin (\frac 1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Sorry, why is it a counterexample?

Comment: $f'(0)=0$ but $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Oh, right. I thought you were trying to show the converse, i.e., the limit exists but it is not differentiable at $0$ (I don't know if that could happen).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thank you, this is only upper high school level so I don't think we would encounter anything like that.

Would the opposing statement be true, that if the limit does not exist, then the function is not differentiable?

Comment: Your updated question can be answered from the counter-example given as well ($\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist, but clearly $f$ is differentiable at 0, since $f'(0)$ exists and equals 0)